# Wifi extender with its own wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-extender

Today I wanted to buy a Wifi Extender, like the Netgear AC750. I thought it could connect to the base station (like the hotel wifi), and then setup its own wifi network, with its own SSID. In the shop they told me this was not the case.

This is what I want:

- Hotel Wifi (ssid=HotelWifi): Extender sets up a connection with the given login
- Extender Wifi (ssid=ExtenderWifi): Phone connects to the extender instead of the hotel wifi

Scenario 2:

- It should be able to act as a normal wifi extender which uses the same SSID

Maybe I misunderstand the way these things work, but I guess this should be possible. I don't know what to ask for in the shop, and the "specialist" there didn't seem to understand what I wanted or didn't have something on the shelves that could do this. At first I thought dual band wifi was what I needed, but now I see that this is about using different frequencies at the same time.

**My question: what kind of wifi extender should I ask for?**

Comment: you want an 'access point' not an 'extender'. Wire it from the source, then use it to provide wifi to your users [same or different SSID is optional]. An extender re-transmits the 'original' wifi signal to a new location, an access point provides a 'new' interface.

Comment: OK thanks. But I don't want to use wire at all. The connection between source and access point should be wireless as well.

Comment: an extender will 'grab' the signal it can see from the last location & push it further, same credentials. In neither situation can you dictate precisely which the user will connect to, if they carry the same SSID [so long as they also carry the same authorisation protocol & p/w etc] if they are different SSIDs, they will require the user to sign in to both.

Comment: I think what I need is a Wifi Hotspot, and the D-Link DIR-510L seems to be able to do it all. Wired+wireless both ways, wireless+wireless with hotspot, and 3G optional with either wired or wireless hotspot.

Comment: We do similar here with our [Ubiquiti UniFi](http://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap/) setup.  The basic fact is you need better than stock, SOHO, off-the-shelf equipment to do things like what you seek.